# Page views in Google Analytics are off compared to a similar metric

Tags: google-analytics

We have a page where a user can sign a pledge to recycle by clicking a pledge button. A script writes it to a text file which updates the number on the page. In the past 2 days there have been 185 pledges signed but only 63 page views in GA.

I trust that they are unique pledges and not just people adding multiple fake names and entering it. Is there anyway to get a better report from Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Is the pledge button a link? If so what HTML tag are you using `<a>`, `<button>` or some other? Does it use `href` or `onclick` AJAX or some other method to write to the file? Bots may be clicking on it, if it's seen as a link. You would know for sure if you view your raw access logs.

I would set an .on() click event and use AJAX to post to your server and update the file. In then use the response to update the number of pledges displayed on the page without a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics works by using JavaScript from Google's servers.  Ad blocking browser add-ons like Ad Block Plus [often block Google Analytics](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14449).  Google Analytics doesn't load for bots and other clients that don't support JavaScript (although I wouldn't expect them to put a name on your form either).

Google Analytics also uses "sampled" data, rather than real data.  Depending on the amount of traffic to your site, it may measure only 10% of your visitors, and extrapolate the reports based on this "representative sample". Some reports in Google Analytics will allow you to include more sampled visitors in the report which can increase accuracy.

Other than that, there is no option in Google Analytics for "show me all the visits".